# procedure failurecompilation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an existing procedure which creates a table `adwstg.switchhold_notificatn_stg`

Suddenly it is throwing error in creating the table. I didn't change anything the statement.

First I thought the error is with ''No'' . So find & replace '' with '

But it is throwing error at line:

```
nvl(ba300_z51.sent_650_01, 'No') sent_650_01,
```

> error(27,29): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NO" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset***

Below is the query :

```
create table adwstg.switchhold_notificatn_stg nologging parallel (degree 8) compress as
select distinct
bad3700.createdon,
bad3700.uc_pod_ext,
bpc.cacont_acc, 
bad3700.notificatn, 
bad3700.nfcat_code, 
nvl(ba300_z51.sent_650_01, ''No'') sent_650_01,
decode(ba300_z51.sent_650_01,''No'',''--'',''Yes'',to_char(ba300_z51.ucswmsgdat,''yyyymmdd''),''--'') date_sent_650_01,
nvl(to_char(ba300_z51.ucswmsgtim,''hh24:mi:ss''),''--'') time_sent_650_01,
nvl(ba300_z52.received_650_02, ''No'') received_650_02,
decode(ba300_z52.received_650_02,''No'',''--'',''Yes'',to_char(ba300_z52.ucswmsgdat,''yyyymmdd''),''--'') date_received_650_02,
nvl(to_char(ba300_z52.ucswmsgtim,''hh24:mi:ss''),''--'') time_received_650_02,
nvl(ba300_z20.received_814_20, ''No'') received_814_20,
decode(ba300_z20.received_814_20,''No'',''--'',''Yes'',to_char(ba300_z20.ucswmsgdat,''yyyymmdd''),''--'') date_received_814_20,
nvl(to_char(ba300_z20.ucswmsgtim,''hh24:mi:ss''),''--'') time_received_814_20,
case
   when trim(bad3700.nfcat_code) = ''SH01'' and zet.ext_ui is not null then ''ADDED''
   when trim(bad3700.nfcat_code) = ''SH01'' and zet.ext_ui is null then ''NOT PROCESSED''
   when trim(bad3700.nfcat_code) in (''SH02'',''SH03'') and zet.ext_ui is null then ''REMOVED''
   when trim(bad3700.nfcat_code) in (''SH02'',''SH03'') and zet.ext_ui is not null then ''NOT PROCESSED''
   else ''NOT PROCESSED''
end work_order_check
from
    (select distinct *
     from
        (select
         trunc(createdon) createdon,
         trim(notificatn) notificatn,
         trim(uc_pod_ext) uc_pod_ext,
         trim(not_type) not_type,
         trim(nfcat_code) nfcat_code,
         row_number () over (partition by trim(uc_pod_ext),trunc(createdon) order by trim(notificatn) desc) rnum
         from birpt.bic_azfc_ds3700
         where upper(trim(not_type)) = ''SH''
         and trim(bic_zdiscstat) = ''E0010'')
     where rnum = 1
    ) bad3700
left outer join
    (
     select distinct ucinstalla, uc_pod_ext, datefrom, dateto
     from birpt.bi0_qucinstalla
     where objvers = ''A''
    ) bqi
    on (trim(bad3700.uc_pod_ext) = trim(bqi.uc_pod_ext)
        and trunc(bad3700.createdon) between bqi.datefrom and bqi.dateto)
left outer join
    (
     select distinct cacont_acc, ucinstalla, ucmovein_d, ucmoveoutd
     from birpt.bi0_puccontract
     where objvers = ''A''
    ) bpc
    on (trim(bqi.ucinstalla) = trim(bpc.ucinstalla)
        and trunc(bad3700.createdon) between bpc.ucmovein_d and bpc.ucmoveoutd)
left outer join 
    (select distinct * 
     from 
        (select
         trim(ucswtpodex) ucswtpodex,
         trunc(ucswmsgdat) ucswmsgdat,
         ucswmsgtim,
         case  --650_01 CHECK
            when trim(uc_mdcat) = ''Z51'' then ''Yes''
            else ''No''
         end sent_650_01,
         row_number () over (partition by trim(ucswtpodex), trunc(ucswmsgdat) order by trunc(ucswmsgdat) desc, ucswmsgtim desc) rnum
         from birpt.bic_azudeds0300
         where trim(uc_mdcat) = ''Z51'') 
     where rnum = 1) ba300_z51
     on (trim(bad3700.uc_pod_ext) = trim(ba300_z51.ucswtpodex)
         and trunc(bad3700.createdon)= trunc(ba300_z51.ucswmsgdat))
left outer join
    (select distinct * 
     from 
        (select
         trim(ucswtpodex) ucswtpodex,
         trunc(ucswmsgdat) ucswmsgdat,
         ucswmsgtim,
         case  --650_02 CHECK
            when trim(uc_mdcat) = ''Z52'' then ''Yes''
            else ''No''
         end received_650_02,
         row_number () over (partition by trim(ucswtpodex), trunc(ucswmsgdat) order by trunc(ucswmsgdat) desc, ucswmsgtim desc) rnum
         from birpt.bic_azudeds0300
         where trim(uc_mdcat) = ''Z52'') 
     where rnum = 1) ba300_z52
     on (trim(bad3700.uc_pod_ext) = trim(ba300_z52.ucswtpodex)
         and trunc(bad3700.createdon)= trunc(ba300_z52.ucswmsgdat))
left outer join
    (select distinct * 
     from 
        (select
         trim(ucswtpodex) ucswtpodex,
         trunc(ucswmsgdat) ucswmsgdat,
         ucswmsgtim,
         case  --814_20 CHECK
            when trim(uc_mdcat) = ''Z20'' then ''Yes''
            else ''No''
         end received_814_20,
         row_number () over (partition by trim(ucswtpodex), trunc(ucswmsgdat) order by trunc(ucswmsgdat) desc, ucswmsgtim desc) rnum
         from birpt.bic_azudeds0300
         where trim(uc_mdcat) = ''Z20'') 
     where rnum = 1) ba300_z20
     on (trim(bad3700.uc_pod_ext) = trim(ba300_z20.ucswtpodex)
         and trunc(bad3700.createdon)= trunc(ba300_z20.ucswmsgdat))
left outer join
    (select distinct ext_ui
     from isurpt.zcs_esiid_tamper
    ) zet
    on (trim(bad3700.uc_pod_ext) = trim(zet.ext_ui));
```

Comment: You might want to produce a [mcve] to make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Why are apparently all single quotes doubled? Is this actually a string you execute with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?

Comment: *'Suddenly it is throwing error '* - nope: procedures don't suddenly start failing. The error means you are doing something different from whatever you were doing before, or there's been some other change of state. We can't tell you what that change is, because we don't have access to your environment and your source control.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all doubled single quotes (perform *replace* function in any text editor), your code will be *valid* (as far as syntax is concerned).

I don't have your tables to test it, and there are too many of them with too many columns to create a test case by myself.

The question is: why did you double them in the first place?